# Is the Characteristic polynomial of $ A $ is a Primitive polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose $ A_{n\times n} $ matrix on $ \Bbb F_{p}  $ ($P$ is prime)  and if the Characteristic polynomial is irreducible then we can make a finite field that the order of $P^n$ with $ A_{n\times n} $ .

$$ \{ 0, I , A^{}, A^{2},A^{3},...,A^{p^{n}-2} \} $$

Is the Characteristic polynomial of $ A_{n\times n} $ is a Primitive polynomial?

**for example:**

I wanna show $x^{3} + x^{2} +2$ is a  Primitive polynomial on $ \Bbb F_{5}  $.

let $A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 4  \end{pmatrix} $ by the cayley hamilton theorem $A^{3} + A^{2} +2 = 0$.

we can show $ \{ 0, I , A^{}, A^{2},A^{3},...,A^{5^{3}-2=123} \} $ is a filed by $125$ order and every field by $5^3$ isomerism. Can i say $x^{3} + x^{2} +2$ is a  Primitive polynomial on $ \Bbb F_{5}$?

Comment: What's the meaning of *a primary polynomial*? I'm not familiar with it. The characteristic polynomial is not necessarily primitive (= if you pick one of its roots, the root generates the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$). Whether it is irreducible/prime depends on whether $A$ generates $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ as a field. It may be that the latter is what you mean with the phrase *we can make a finite field $\Bbb{F}_{P^n}$ with $A$*, but honestly I cannot tell. Can you clarify these points. It is possibly an imperfect translation. That's ok, but there are subtleties.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  thanks a lot. i edit my question